# MYSQL use LEAST() or GREATEST() functions in WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, unpivot

I Have a lot of columns to process in a query (columns result can be also NULL) and at the end i need an unique list of all pieces for a timetable (e.g. "what part of what piece i should work first")

my table is something like this

```
piece type | deadline for first check | deadline for second check | deadline for third check | deadline for n. check
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FIRST      | NULL                     | 2022-02-01                | 2022-01-18               | 2022-04-01
SECOND     | 2022-03-01               | 2022-01-15                | 2022-03-15               | 2022-05-01
```

Current query and php processing (slow) give me out something like :

```
2022-01-15 SECOND (second check)
2022-03-01 SECOND (first check)
2022-05-01 SECOND (n. check)
2022-01-18 FIRST  (third check)
...
```

As i've more than 600 pieces (of different types) and 6-7 checks to do (in total, but something like 4 for a piece type, 2 for a piece type and so on) i would like to know if is there a way to limit (let's say "least of deadlines < today" or something like 'least of deadlines within 10 days ) if (php based) is there "no filtering" list (on piece type)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I assume English is not your first language, but I am a little confused as to what you are actually asking in the question?

Comment: Why is the deadline for a "third check" sooner than for the "second check"??

Comment: i'm italian so i'm sorry if can't explain completely... but deadlines can be sooner if (e.g.) first deadline for a piece is after 2 months, but third deadline for a piece is after 1 month

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like:

```
SELECT piece_type, check_date, which
    FROM (
        SELECT piece_type, deadline1 AS check_date, 1 AS which
            FROM tbl WHERE deadline1 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT piece_type, deadline2 AS check_date, 2 AS which
            FROM tbl WHERE deadline2 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT piece_type, deadline3 AS check_date, 3 AS which
            FROM tbl WHERE deadline3 IS NOT NULL
         )  AS x
    ORDER BY check_date;
```